# Several Issues With Code That Appears to Be Working Perfectly Fine

Tags: roblox

I am currently working to make a TD[Tower Defense] game on Roblox. As of now I am working on the pathing of the monsters/NPC's. However, during debugging, I noticed that one of my changes completely broke the code, and with no errors, I am stumped on what's happening.
Issues:

1. Mobs are not spawning. Checking the hierarchy, nothing named "Zombie," or "Monster," is spawning, yet the base is still being damaged.
2. When the mobs still did spawn, they moved in a straight line towards the goal, not through each of the waypoints.

The current module script for summoning said NPC's is as below:

```lua
-- Service
local ServerStorage = game:GetService("ServerStorage")
local PhysicsService = game:GetService("PhysicsService")
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
-- Variable
local GroupPlayer = "GroupPlayer"
local GroupMobs = "GroupMobs"
local baseHP = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage").Values["Base HP"]
-- Module
local module = {}

function module.SpawnMobs(Map, Mob, Count, Cooldown)
    for count = 1, Count do
        local dmgToDeal = nil
        local Monster = ServerStorage.Mobs:FindFirstChild(Mob):Clone()
        Monster:FindFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart").Position = Map.Path[1].Position
        Monster.Parent = workspace

        task.spawn(function()
            for CurrentPathPoint = 1, #Map.Path:GetChildren() do
                Monster.Humanoid:MoveTo(Map.Path[CurrentPathPoint].Position)    
            end
            if Monster.Humanoid.Health ~= 0 then
                dmgToDeal = Monster.Humanoid.Health
            end
            baseHP.Value = baseHP.Value - dmgToDeal
            Monster:Destroy()
        end)

        task.wait(Cooldown - math.random(-1,1))
    end 
end

return module
```

This module is being called from a script in ServerScriptStorage that runs every 5 seconds.

Comment: Code doesn't execute in [ServerStorage](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/ServerStorage). Did you mean [ServerScriptService](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/ServerScriptService)?

Comment: Oh. Thank you for informing me